What if content from subsequent provisional applications contradict previous applications?
I understand that if multiple provisional applications are filed within the 12 month period for the same application, then the content in each provisional will have their own priority date.
This is all clear to me if each subsequent provisional adds new matter.
However, what happens in the event that subsequent provisionals contradict or retract statements made in previous provisionals?
For example:
Provisional application 1: "the widget A requires minimally feature X".
Provisional application 2: "the widget A requires minimally feature Y".

Each Provisional stands on its own. Provisional applications for patent cannot claim the benefit of a previously-filed application, either foreign or domestic. This means that provisional applications cannot "add new matter" and multiple provisionals cannot be filed "for the same application".
From the point of view of a provisional application, there is no "previous" application. Each is independent of the others.
So, there cannot be a "conflict" between provisional applications. The provisional applications are not related to each other until they are used for a priority date in a non-provisional application / PCT application. If the more restrictive is in a later-filed provisional, and there is not other subject matter you need from it, just don't use it for a priority date.
If one of those two statements is used in a claim, then the claim would only have a priority date of the provisional in which that statement was included.
If there are mutually exclusive conditions in two provisionals and both provisionals will be used as a priority, then you would just use the description of the first provisional as a "first aspect of the disclosure" and the description of the second provisional as a "second aspect of the disclosure". Now, there is no conflict since the conditions are not applied to the exact same embodiment of the invention.
